# Historical Moon’s True Anomaly Numbers

Tags: the-moon

What are moon’s true anomaly angles for new moons in year 1994? Cannot find historical true anomaly numbers on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

The [JPL Horizons System](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) website can generate orbital elements which include the true anomaly.

You will need to know the dates and times that you want. If that is not available from Horizons (I did not do an exhaustive search), you can get the Moon's phase from the U.S. Naval Observatory's Data Services [Dates of Primary Phases of the Moon](https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/MoonPhases) website.